# As of today, there were plans

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

What does "As of today" mean with a past-tense verb, as follows?

> **As of today**, there **were** plans to deliver an additional 12 RD-181 engines in 2022-2024 and talks **were** also held with the United States on the delivery of RD-181M engines with improved operational characteristics . . .

http://lite.cnn.com/en/article/h_a20fe2329df17b315fe93bfe51276795

Does it mean "Starting today" or "So far"?

The source text deals with Russia's decision to stop supplying rocket engines to the US.

<sup>Entire quote, to save people clicking through. The sentence construction is so poor it really shouldn't be taken as an example</sup>

> "As of today, there were plans to deliver an additional 12 RD-181 engines in 2022-2024 and talks were also held with the United States on the delivery of RD-181M engines with improved operational characteristics, but we believe that in this situation we can no longer supply the United States with our best engines," the Roscosmos head said.

Comment: I don't know whether the Russian being quoted spoke in English or whether it's a poor translation, but what he _should_ have said was "There were plans to deliver [engines to the USA]... but as of today [those plans are cancelled.]" It doesn't make sense to say "As of today there _were_..."

Comment: @KateBunting - I didn't read the linked article until now. I agree, it's either a poor translation or poor interpretation… or the speaker didn't have his ducks in a row before he started speaking off the cuff.

Comment: How about "As of today, there **have been** plans to deliver an additional 12 RD-181 engines in 2022-2024 and talks **have also been held**"?

Comment: Kate's re-cast is your best bet. The original construction is deeply flawed. It's referring to past events then later comparing to 'today'. The 'today' part comes right at the end. "It was this, but *as of today* it is now that"

Comment: What does "As of today" mean in Kate's version? "So far" or "Starting today"?

Comment: See my answer… that's what it's there for. 'at this particular moment in time'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"As of today" is newspaper-ese.
Others would include "as of now", "as of yesterday" or "as from tomorrow".

It could be replaced with simply "today" or left out entirely.
The sentence would normally need a slight re-cast to eliminate it… "Today, plans were made…" or just "Plans have been made…"

It does reinforce the aspect of 'at this particular moment in time' but it's a stock phrase.

<sup>This answer is based entirely on the quote extract as originally provided here. The full linked quote is a fairly clumsy construction altogether & shouldn't be relied on as an example of 'correct English'.

It's referring to past events then later comparing to 'today'. The 'today' part comes right at the end. "It was this, but as of today it is now that"</sup>